# How to test angular directive scope: true

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having some trouble reaching my return statement for my angular test.  I am using jasmine with karma, and bard js.  I used the ng2html preprocesser to **$templateCache**

**templatesCached** is the module name given to the files in my templates folder.  **ha.module.core** Houses the directive that I want to test.  I am reaching it when I run my debugging tools.

Below is my test.  They pass, but the issue I am having is that **rootScope** does not hold any particular values.   Also

```
element.html() // returns "" in the console.  I was expecting my directive back.  Is this wrong?
```

After I run through controller = element.scope I am getting

```
html = [div.ng-scope]





describe(" directive", function () {
    var element,
        template,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function () {
        bard.appModule("templatesCached", "ha.module.core");



        bard.inject(
            "$compile",
            "$controller",
            "$rootScope",
            "haConfig"
        );
    });



    beforeEach(function () {

        var html = angular.element("<div explore-hero></div>");

        spyOn(myService, "getTemplateUrl");
        //console.log("html ", html);

        $rootScope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = $compile(html)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest(element);
        controller = element.scope();

        element.controller('heroController');
```

Element.controller is an anonymous function.

```
        console.log('element', element);

    });


    it("should have a div element", function () {
        var result = element[0].querySelectorAll(".container");
        expect(element.length).toBe(1); // not a ideal test for creation
        expect(result).toBeDefined();
    });


});
```

Here is my template cached.

```
    module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('/templates/explore-hero-base-template.html',
    '<div class="container">\n' +
    '    <div share-widget></div>\n' +
    '///html divs and info'
    '</div><!-- .container -->');
}]);
```

My directive

```
  angular.module('ha.module.core').directive('exploreHero', function(myService) {
   var HeroController = function($scope) {
       $scope.emit('methods')
   };

   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      templateUrl: myService.getTemplateUrl('explore-hero.html),
      controller: 'HeroController
    }
)
```

Any insight would help

Comment: Please, revise the code. The actual directive code is missing. `element.controller('exploreHero');` isn't related to anything. It is not clear what the question is, there are no specs for scope.

Comment: Added a scaled down version of my directive